# Information and Page from Wordpress Plugin

Tags: plugin-development, forms, wp-redirect

I couldn't really find the best solution for my problem - maybe I'm missing the forest through the trees. I developed a plugin that displays a html sign-up form for a newsletter. The collected info is encoded and sent to a custom CRM via API via `wp_remote_post`. All is hooked to the `template_redirect`.

To make it user friendly I'd like to redirect to a custom page after submission is done, calling the visitor by his name and thanking them for signing up.

I want this 'thank you' page following the theme anyone having the plugin is currently using and also send a customized welcome message. What would be best practice? Thank you in advance!

Comment: I think your best bet would be to use AJAX to just remove the form and display the success/thank you message directly on the same page rather than getting into redirecting.

Comment: There's no code in your question to work with, can you include the code? Keep in mind this isn't a discussion form, you need to be able to mark an answer as not just the best response, but as ***the*** canonical answer, written using facts, for all users who might ever have this question